# Why can't I set $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as Attribute?

Tags: php, oop, attributes

Why can't I set `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as attribute?
see example code

```
class foo
{
private $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // generates error
private $blah;

public function __construct()
{
//code
}

  public function setBla($bla)
  {
   $this->blah = $bla;

  }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in test.php on line 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot use other variable when initializing in declaration. try this:

```
class foo
{
private $path;
private $blah;

public function __construct()
{
$this->$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//code
}

  public function setBla($bla)
  {
   $this->blah = $bla;

  }
}
```

by the way, are you sure private is an appropriate choice, often protected is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

[Class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) can only be initialized with constant values:

> […] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

So you need to initialize them in the constructor like mathroc said.